# Laravel Filter JSON Data with SQL LIKE Operator

Tags: json, laravel, eloquent

**Code**

```
 //text to search   
     $details  = "Successfully";
        
        ActivityLog::with('getCauserDetails')
        ->when($details ?? false, function ($q) use ($details) {
            $q->whereJsonContains('properties->activity', $details);
        })
        ->get()
        ->toArray();
```

**Table Structure**

```
id          - int
name        - varchar
properties  - json
user_id     - int
```

**Json Data**

```
{
   "ip":"192.168.0.1",
   "platform":"Windows",
   "activity":"Successfully logout"
}

{
   "ip":"192.168.0.1",
   "device":"WebKit",
   "browser":"Chrome",
   "platform":"Windows",
   "activity":"Successfully logged in"
}
```

**Question**: Above code have been successfully to search the value of data inside the JSON data but need to search into full sentence. For example, **"Successfully logout"**, if I search with **"Successfully"** sentence, it's will not filter the data. Does anyone know how to filter it's with the **SQL LIKE Operator** inside the `JsonContains`, mean that if I filter with sentence "Successfully", it's will also return the data instead of full sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find any appropriate Laravel method but your query in SQL would be like this. It seems you don't have other choice except using **raw query**:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_name
WHERE JSON_EXTRACT(properties, "$.activity") LIKE '%Successfully logout%'
```